# OpenLayers Map markers disappear when map is centered on them

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, openlayers, markers

I'm having issues with the OpenLayers map markers. I have searched through the other answers here and on other sites but non of them really addressed the issue I'm having (at least I don't think they did. I'm fairly new to OpenLayers and Javascript, my apologies if I am wrong).

The markers appear when I load the map and page, and no errors display in the console. When I pan to the markers, as they cross into the middle third of the map at max extent, they disappear! When I zoom in, they disappear before I can even get them on screen (never errors from the console). Here is my javascript code for generating the map and markers. Thank you in advance for all of your help.

Additional notes: When I use static numbers (and not values retrieved from my XML file) for marker positioning, the markers do not disappear on pan or zoom. I am so confused.

RESOLVED: I used a different XML file and the markers stopped disappearing for some reason, I have no idea why.

Code:

```js
  $(function()
  {
     var map = new OpenLayers.Map("rcp1_map");

      layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OpenStreetMap");
      map.addLayer(layer);

      map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
      map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0), 3);

      var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
      map.addLayer(markers);

     //load and retrieve values from XML file here
     var xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("http://whxlab3.dart.ns.ec.gc.ca/~brinka/
             EMETsiteV1/EMETsite.xml");
     var z=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("buoy_number");
     var y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lat");
     var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("long");

     //create and add all map markers here
     for(i=0; i<x.length; i++)
     {
         //use loaded XML file to retrieve values for marker positions
         var px = x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
         var py = y[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
         var pz = z[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
         console.log("Testing Console", px, py);
         var size = new OpenLayers.Size(32, 37);
         var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
         var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('stock_images/buoy_arrow.png', size,
                     offset);
         icon.setOpacity(0.7);


         var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(px, py);
         lonlat.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                     new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));

         var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat, icon);

         marker.events.register("mouseover", marker, function(){
            console.log("Over the marker "+this.id+" at place
                            "+this.lonlat);
            this.inflate(1.2);
            this.setOpacity(1);
        });

        marker.events.register("mouseout", marker, function(){
            console.log("Out the marker "+this.id+" at place
                            "+this.lonlat);
            this.inflate(1/1.2);
            this.setOpacity(0.7);
        });
        marker.events.register("click", marker, function(){
            console.log("Clicked "+this.id+" at place "+this.lonlat);
            popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken",
                            marker.lonlat, new OpenLayers.Size(200, 200), 
                            ("Buoy Number: "+pz), null, true);
            map.addPopup(popup);
        });

        markers.addMarker(marker);

    }
    //:*** To here
});
```

Comment: @kryger Did you change anything aside from striking out the first sentence and my code? :(

Comment: Yep, code highlighting. You can click the "edited XX mins ago" link to see the details.

Comment: @kryger Checked the details - nothing within the actual code was changed then? In other words, no solution was found?

Comment: @user1708754 a solution would be specified in an answer, not in an edit to the question.

Comment: To make it easier to investigate you could include a sample of actual `lat` and `long`s from "EMETsite.xml" (you don't seem to be using `buoy_number`). Turning this into a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be even better (you could try reusing some existing fiddles - easily googleable).

Comment: @kryger I will look into the JSFiddle, thank you!